# Google Mock unit testing static methods c++

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I just started working on unit testing (using BOOST framework for testing, but for mocks I have to use Google Mock) and I have this situation :

```
class A
{
static int Method1(int a, int b){return a+b;}
};

class B
{
static int Method2(int a, int b){ return A::Method1(a,b);}
};
```

So, I need to create mock class A, and to make my class B not to use real Method1 from A class, but to use mock.

I'm not sure how to do this, and I could not find some similar example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gmock, but couldn't you just link `B.o` and `mockA.o`?

Comment: As far as I know, there is some different way dealing with static methods.
I could probably solve this with making Method1 to be virtual, and to add constructor in class B, so it looks something like B(A &a):a_in_class_b(a){}, and then call of Method1 would look like this : a_in_class_b->Method1();
But I want to see if there is some other way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could change class B into a template :

```
template< typename T >
class B
{
public:
static int Method2(int a, int b){ return T::Method1(a,b);}
};
```

and then create a mock :

```
struct MockA
{
  static MockCalc *mock;
  //This class is passed as template type during class B object creation in unit test environment
  static int Method1(int a, int b){ return mock->Method1(a,b);}
};
class MockCalc {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD2(Method1, int(int,int));
};
```

Before every test, initialize the static mock object `MockA::mock`.

Another option is to instead call directly `A::Method1`, create a functor object (maybe std::function type) in class B, and call that in the Method2. Then, it is simpler, because you would not need MockA, because you would create a callback to MockCalc::Method1 to this object. Something like this :

```
class B
{
public:
static std::function< int(int,int) > f;
static int Method2(int a, int b){ return f(a,b);}
};

class MockCalc {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD2(Method1, int(int,int));
};
```

and to initialize it :

```
MockCalc mock;
B::f = [&mock](int a,int b){return mock.Method1(a,b);};
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

[jomock](https://github.com/jonah512/jomock) is one of the feasible solutions for Windows application case

```
class A
{
public:
    static int Method1(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    static int Method2(int a, int b){
        return A::Method1(a, b);
    }
};


TEST(JoMock, Method1Test)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(JOMOCK(A::Method1), JOMOCK_FUNC(_, _))
        .WillRepeatedly(Return(3));

    EXPECT_EQ(B::Method2(1, 3), 3);
}
```

B::Method2(1, 3) returns 3 in this case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30750413)

Comment: Well. the original question was "how to mock static functions", and I also have looked for the way to mock static or non-virtual method to avoid modification of legacy source code. "jomock" provides a solution with simple syntax by using function hook internally.

Comment: Well, the problem I see is that your answer is kind of side remark, and as such it would suffice if you left a simple comment under the question, pointing out that jomock offers another solution for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A variant version based on BЈовић's answer that allows not to use template (and error-prone explicit template specialization if your implementation is not in the header files).
However, this will need to make the class A not static anymore.

First, create an interface class

```
class AIf
{
int Method1(int a, int b) = 0;
};
```

Let your class A implements AIf

```
class A : AIf
{
int Method1(int a, int b){return a+b;}
};
```

Then in your class B, add a static pointer to the AIf

```
class B
{
static AIf* impl = nullptr;
static int Method2(int a, int b) {return impl->Method1(a, b)}
};
```

When GMock, just do

```
class MockA : AIf {
MOCK_METHOD2(Method1, int(int a, int b));
};
```

Then in your tests, set the impl before calling any functions

```
MockA mockA;
EXPECT_CALL(...);

B::impl = &mockA;
B::Method2(a, b);
```