# How to use gmock to mock up a std::function?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, googletest, googlemock

The constructor of my class is

```
A( ...
   std::function<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)> aCallBack, 
   ... );
```

I want to use EXPECT_CALL to test it. This callback is from another class B. I created a Mock like

```
class BMock : public B
{
    MOCK_METHOD2( aCallBack, bool(const std::string&, const std::string&) );
}
```

Then I tried

```
B *b = new B();
std::function<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)> func = 
    std::bind(&B::aCallBack, b, std::PlaceHolders::_1, std::PlaceHolders::_2);
```

It still does not work. How can I get a function pointer of a gmock object?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to use mock to keep track of calls and set return values, you can use [`MockFunction`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/d9c55a48eddbc92434454ac2b28771870750e616/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mock-stdfunction-mockfunction).

```cpp
using testing::_;
using testing::MockFunction;
using testing::Return;

MockFunction<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)> mockCallback;

EXPECT_CALL(mockCallback, Call(_, _)).WillOnce(Return(false)); // Or anything else you want to do

A( ...
   mockCallback.AsStdFunction()
   ...);
```

Comment: This is golden. Been looking for this across multiple related stack overflow posts, and your answer was the first I found that mentioned MockFunction and provided a complete example.

Comment: I am not sure why this was never mentioned in the documentation. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's documented in Cookbook at least - https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mock-stdfunction-mockfunction

Comment: Unfortunately, all `MockFunction`s are identified as `Call` in error messages which is very unhelpful...

Answer (score -3):

With unit testing you should only test your class A so your test should just check if *any* function passed to the constructor gets called.
So you don't need a mock, instead just pass a lambda that just record with a boolean (or a counter).

```
bool gotCalled = false;
A a( [&gotCalled]( const std::string&, const std::string& ) { gotCalled = true; return true; } );
...
ASSERT_TRUE( gotCalled );
```

Comment: Anyway, although it's fine passing a function to the constructor, architecturally it doesn't smell right if it's used as callback. Generally it would be better to pass it to the function that actually is using it.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with an actual solution to TS problem, for the actual answer please check Enzam's answer