# How to mock a structure of std::functions using gmock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have this code in C++11

```
struct Callbacks
{
    using StartFunc = std::function<bool()>;
    StartFunc start;

    using FinishFunc = std::function<bool(int status)>;
    FinishFunc finish;
};

// this registers the callbacks and calls the 2 functions 
int do_something(const Callbacks& callbacks)
{
   ...
   callbacks.start(true);
   
   ...
   callbacks.finish(true);  
}
```

And I want to mock the callbacks, to make sure they are called properly.
I read
[How to use gmock to mock up a std::function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521088/how-to-use-gmock-to-mock-up-a-stdfunction)
and I did something like this

```
MockFunction<Callbacks::start> startFuncMock;
MockFunction<Callbacks::stop> finishFuncMock;
```

but when I call my function

```
Callbacks cb;
cb.start = startFuncMock; // this does not compile

do_something(cb);
```

How can I make it work? thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You didn't seem to read carefully the answer in the linked question. It should be `cb.start = startFuncMock.AsStdFunction();`. The question has been closed as a dup.

Comment: Please don't use the tag [gmock] anymore, it's a Groovy mocking framework. You again didn't seem to read carefully the tag description. Always reading information casually is not a good habit.