# GMOCK - mock an object and its inside mock method

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am writing a GMOCK test cases for a class:

```
class A{ .. void Text() .. };
```

Now one of the member method of class A has an class B type object embedded into it and also refers to static member methods:

```
void A::Text()
{
B bobj;
B::SMethod();
bobj->BMethod();
......
}
```

In such a case how can I mock B and its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing `A`, you can test a class derived from it, let's call it `TestableA`. In `A` make `Text()` `virtual` and in override use mock of the `B`. Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942330/google-mock-unit-testing-static-methods-c) for more  ideas of how to mock classes with static methods.

Nevertheless, the best solution would be to break existing tight dependency between `A` and `B` by introducing an interface (e.g. `InterfaceB`) and injecting it into `Text()`. `SMethod()` would become a (non-static) member of the interface. In production you'd be injecting `ActualB` where `ActualB::SMethod()` calls `static` `B::SMethod()`. In tests you'd use `MockB::SMethod()`, tailored by test needs.