# Mock a function of another class in another class method

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am trying to GMOCK a class:

```
class A
{
public:

void method1()
{
std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;
}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
void method1()
{
............
A::method1();
............
}
};
```

How can I write test case for class B method1 to call mock method of class A method1 when referred in the flow? Hence B's method1 should be called upon but when it needs to call A's method1 - it should instead call mock method and continue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942330/google-mock-unit-testing-static-methods-c

Comment: I have removed static qualifier - the issue is that in between B's method2 call A's method is invoked - hence I want to mocK A's method only remaining should execute B's method2